# Getting prev and next buttons to work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm started recently to learn PHP and PDO. While I read some tutorials I've create one simple site with 2 pages. `index.php` and `single.php`. On the index page I load images from database(this is done). Then when I click on single image is go to `single.php` where this image is displayed(done this also). Now I'm trying to make buttons for next and previous image from database. I'm not so sure how is this working but after reading some tutorials I think I've got the idea.

This is the link on the `index.php` which redirect to `single.php`

```
<a href="single.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'">
   <img src="'.$row['image_name'].'"/>
</a>
```

Here is `single.php` ( part of it )

```
if(isset($_GET['image_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['image_id']))
{
    $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];
    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id= ? LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->execute(array($_GET['image_id']))) 
    {      
       if($row = $result->fetch())
       {
          $update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE images SET image_hits = image_hits + 1 WHERE image_id = ?");
          $update->bindParam(1, $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $update->execute();
          echo ' // image data ';
       }
    }
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly how is work I need current id which should be `image_id`, next id and prev id. It's sound kind of easy.. but not for me. I've thing that I need something like this but the problem is where and how to implement it into current code that I have?

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id > $image_id ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 1");

if($result){
    $next_id = $result->fetch();
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id < $image_id ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1");
if($result){
    $prev_id = $result->fetch();
}

if($result){

   //construct next/previous button
   $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'"><img src="prev.png" /></a>':'';
   $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'"><img src="next.png" /></a>':'';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

1. The `prepare` method doesn't return the result directly. It returns an executable statement. They needed to be executed explicitly.
2. With prepared statements, you should put the `$image_id` through the prepared statement instead of attach it before prepare.
3. The method `fetch()` doesn't return the `$prev_id` or `$next_id`. Instead, it returns a result row. By default, it should be an associated array with keys equal to fields in the row.

To fix your code should look something like this:

```
// get next picture id
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id > :image_id ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 1');
if($stmt){
    $stmt->execute(array(':image_id' => $image_id));
    if (($row = $result->fetch()) !== FALSE) {
       $next_id = $row['image_id'];
    }
}

// get previous picture id
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE image_id < :image_id ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1');
if($stmt){
    $stmt->execute(array(':image_id' => $image_id));
    if (($row = $result->fetch()) !== FALSE) {
       $prev_id = $row['image_id'];
    }
}

// construct next/previous button
$prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'"><img src="prev.png" /></a>':'';
$next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'"><img src="next.png" /></a>':'';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And where should be this portion of the code? Inside if statement after this if ($result->execute(array($_GET['image_id']))) or somewhere else?

Comment: The input parameter in `execute` should be an assoc array. The key should match the placeholder in your prepared query string. For instance, since I used `:image_id` as placeholder in the SQL string, I used `array(':image_id' => $image_id)` in execute. You may read [related documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for further study.

Comment: Ok, I've almost got it to work but there is the problem with next and prev links. It is like `http://localhost/sitefolder/2/` should be `http://localhost/single.php?image_id=2`. How I've got this? I don't have .htaccess or something that can rewrite URL`s?

Comment: I don't get it. If you generated the links in `http://localhost/single.php?image_id=2` format, why would you get links like `http://localhost/sitefolder/2/` in your site?

Comment: I've got it to work. Was forget `?image_id='.$next_id.'` on the href link. Thank you again for the help!